# Paypal ipn found code where it stops working PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I got to check out deeper into my paypal ipn code. I used INSERTS to make sure I know where the code stops working. The code will not pass this section. Here is the code:

```
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
```

Thus, it never reaches

```
            if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

Here is most of the code:

```
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 

if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {    

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

Does anybody know why it does not pass this section of the paypal ipn code?

Comment: You've given a line of code, but no context. What's `$fp`? Is it set properly? Is it pointing at something? Are there errors in your log file? Does the program crash, hang, what?

Comment: `echo $x` fail - pls debug

Comment: @Dagon - Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Any ideas on how I should fix it?

Comment: @user3109009 - there's literally no way we can fix it. You've given us a single line of code, and tell us there's something wrong. But you've not included anything that we can use to help you - how are we supposed to know what `$fp` is? Help us to help you.

Comment: Do you want to use the sandbox?

Comment: Should I remove it and go with Paypal instead? let me try..